# Crystal Reports Section Arrangement

Tags: crystal-reports, formatting

I am currently working on a Crystal Report wherein I use three different commands. 
I use the first command to display the details on the header of the report while the other two commands contain two sets of data for the report body itself.

My problem is that the report's format should be grouped into two wherein the first group will appear after the header and the second group will appear after the first group. To give you a better view of it, please refer to the sample below:

```
CLASS CODE: AC01
SECTION   : A
TEACHER   : Ms. Teacher 1

GROUP 1
      NAME           AGE           BIRTHDATE
    Student 1        19            12-01-1990
    Student 2        22            08-04-1987
    Student 3        20            07-07-1989

SCHEDULE
      TIME           DAY             SUBJECT          
    10-11 AM         MWF           HISTORY 101
    12-01 PM         MWF           BIOLOGY 202
    02-04 PM         TTh           BIOLOGY LAB
```

Please note that I am using TextTools for GROUP 1 and SECTION Labels. I have tried adding a new Header and placing the 'GROUP 1' in it then the preceeding Details Section contains the data for Group 1. However, I cannot add another Header below the Details Section so that I can start working with the SCHEDULE.

Are there any workarounds for this problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: Does your command for the header return just a single record, or multiple records? What is TextTools? Are you using any groups in Group Expert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright,

I did some other research and this is what I got: http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=12033

Apparently, I had to use SUBREPORTS.

Thanks for the help! :)